# applying collation to sql server databases

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, collation

I am currently working with applying collations to my sql server databases which are housed on a database server - sql server 2012.

Each of the databases will have different collations as the data varies from Latin, to Cryillic and one Arabic database.

I have 3 questions:

1. Is it possible to apply a number of collations to the same sql server database?
2. The fact databases of different collations are on the same database server, could their potential for conflict between the collation of the server and the databases?
3. Finally - is there a script I can use to apply a collation to each of the databases, noting they are created and contain data?

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to apply a number of collations to the same sql server
>   database?

The database collation is just the default for new columns in that database.  You can specify different collations all you like as long as it's for different columns.  You can even specify collation in views or ad-hoc SQL.

> The fact databases of different collations are on the same database
>   server, could their potential for conflict between the collation of
>   the server and the databases?

The server collation is just the default collation for a new database.  Typically, it's also the collation used by `master` and `tempdb`.  That means queries against temporary tables require you to explicitly specify the collation.

> Finally - is there a script I can use to apply a collation to each of
>   the databases, noting they are created and contain data?

You can use the [alter database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174269.aspx) command:

```
ALTER DATABASE TestDb ALTER COLLATION French_CI_AI
```

Note that all existing columns will keep their collation.  As said, the database collation is just the default for new columns.

Comment: Many thanks for this information - I have 2 follow up questions on this. 1. How can I alter the collation on existing columns? 2. If I wanted column to store data from different collations, is this possible? Could there be an issue with this setup - eg. Cyrillic and Latin data in the same column.

Comment: 1. `alter table ... alter column ...` works, 2. collation just affects sorting and comparison.  Storing would work fine (as long as you use a Unicode column, i.e. `nvarchar` instead of `varchar`)

Comment: Great stuff, thanks for this info - any way to generate a script to alter the collation of an entire database?